# Google chart table - show multiple pages side by side

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm making a table chart using the Google Charts tools, which displays data from a similar query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_count, name FROM users_statistics GROUP BY name;
```

The chart then displays three columns - entry number, count number and username. The problem is, it has way too much data (around 8000 entries) and the table itself is very thin. What I want is to utilize the available white space by splitting the table in two parts, which stay side by side - something like this:

[image: Table chart on two pages]

Is there an easy way to do this without too much trouble with Google Charts or any other chart library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataViews to split your data into multiple sections, and then draw multiple tables.  Syncing sorting and paging between tables could get a bit tricky, but it should be doable.  Here's a basic example:

```
// split a 2000 row DataTable "data" into two 1000 row DataViews
var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view1.setRows(0, 999);
var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view2.setRows(1000, 1999);

var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.querySelector('#table_1'));
table1.draw(view1, {/* options */});
var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.querySelector('#table_2'));
table2.draw(view2, {/* options */});
```

Comment: Thank you. Tweaked it a bit and worked like a charm :)